# How to create function when load dynamic content in XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I calling function **collapseandexpand()** only for static element, then it will not work, so now how to create the same function when load dynamic content in **xslt**.

Javascript Code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text>
function collapseandexpand(){
if(document.getElementById ('subList').style.display == 'none')
document.getElementById ('subList').style.display = 'block';
else
document.getElementById ('subList').style.display = 'none';         
}
</xsl:text>
</script>
```

Comment: So what is the problem, that your XSLT code generates several `id="subList"` elements in the same document? The `id` needs to be unique to be able to make use of `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen:Here generated some dynamic divs.Now i'm trying to expanding and collapsing each div.But only first is working expand and collapse remaining divs are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XSLT code to

```
 <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="subDiv">
    <a href="#" onClick="collapseandexpand(document.getElementById('{generate-id()}'))">
        <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
        </span>
    </a>                
    </div>
    <div class="childsubDiv" id="{generate-id()}" >
    <ul id="subMenu" class="subMenu">
        <xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
         <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number"/>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
             <xsl:with-param name="context" select="$context"/>
             </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then the script function to

```
function collapseandexpand (element) {
  element.style.display = element.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: i have small doubt {generate-id()} means it is automatically generated id's?

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working fine.Thanks a lot @Martin Honnen

Comment: i added css but not displaying images for expand and collapse

Comment: Please ask a new question about the CSS problem, stating clearly what you want to achieve and showing what you have tried.